# Being able to connect from one RHES host to another with No network running on the target host

Tags: linux, rhel

I have two redhat (RHES 7.7) hosts running side by side. One of them (the affected) encountered "authorisation is not available check polkit running". The outcome is that no network is running on the affected host. I can only access the affected host through direct VDI connection for now. I I can run commands and see the output but no copies etc. My windows 10 computer could access both hosts through MobaXterm/putty. But without network this access to the affected host does no work. Is there anyway I can connect these two hosts through some cable say serial to USB port cable with male serial cable connected to the serial port on the back of the affected host and USB connected to the healthy host that can be accessed through MobaXterm? The idea is that I should be able to access the healthy host with MobaXterm and through that the affected host. Will this setup work as a temporary measure?

Thanks

[image]

worth adding that these two hosts are also connected through local area network with NETGEAR Gigabit Ethernet switch besides the usual internet connection.

Each host has an additional ethernet card besides the usual card that is used for internet. However if I ping the local IP address it comes back with network is unreachable. Note that connection 5 (affected host) is not lighting up.

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to repair the affected system?

Comment: Depending on what configuration doesn't work, you might still have IPv6 link-local connectivity. What does `ip -6 -br addr` show?

Comment: Hi Bruce. Yes that is correct

Comment: Hi A.B it says a one liner

lo    UNKNOWN    ::1/128

Comment: added some comments to the main body.

Comment: If you need to send a binary fix over serial, you can use e.g. [kermit](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/ckermit/kermit.1.en.html).

Comment: Sorry only the loopback ::1 : no link-local IPv6 to rely on. As the interface is probably down (since there's no light on the switch) that was to be expected.